# Problem with converting from lyx file to PDF

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I'm trying to convert from latex to PDF but whenever i hit CTRL+R, a message appears that reads:

```
File does not exist: C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6680/lyx_tmpbuf2/assignment1.pdf
```

I'm not even sure if what I'm doing is correct. Is there another way to convert to PDF?
Been searching online and can't find any answer that helps, most say I have to do update or install a program, but I do not have that option as i do not have administrator rights for the computer I'm using.

I have an assignment due to tonight, but I need it converted to pdf from lyx. I know this may be crazy, but if anyone is willing, I'd like to send my lyx file over email so they can convert it to pdf and send it back to me. I'm just a guy who really needs help ASAP. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Would you mind doing it from command prompt?. If on windows, I can give you a `.bat` file which you put in the same folder as your `.lyx` file and double click.

Comment: if it is only one lyx file, you could export this to a tex file and then upload the tex file to [sharelatex](http://www.sharelatex.com) and convert it there. I have had this problem before and as far as I remember, the tex export still worked. Unfortunately, sharelatex is down for the moment (apparently in response to heartbleed) but maybe worthwhile to try anyway.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you guys!! Just realized that my assingment is actually due this week Friday. @vaettchen Thanks. I'll try that out!